# How can I control one android device with another android device?

Tags: remote-control, vnc

How can I use android device A to view and interact with android device B? I want total control not just accessing the file system our certain features. VNC maybe?

Comment: You already tagged your question VNC -- so give it a try :) Yes, that would be a possibility -- but most likely will require you to root your device. I added the `remote-control` tag to your question: just follow it, there will certainly be similar questions with answers to get you started. Yupp: [Remote connection between two android devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38652/16575)

Comment: Yes I could just experiment and try and figure it out myself our I could post a question on a Q&A site so I hopefully don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Matt, you could check the places I've mentioned to see if there's something already answering your question. The link I posted in my previous comment looks like it is the same stuff you are looking for. If that does *not* answer your question, you can simply update your above post indicating you checked that and giving the reasons why your question is different. I was not *complaining*, but hinting to possible solutions ;)